# Where to find Periodic Sobolev spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am interested in periodic travelling waves for the Gross-Pitaevskii equation... so I need to manage with periodic sobolev spaces. Can anyone give me some good references for this?

I have tried with the classical book by H. Brezis but it does not Work with periodic sobolev spaces.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One good reference for periodic Sobolev spaces (and more generally periodic distributions)  and their applications to PDEs is the book *Fourier Analysis and Partial Differential Equations* by Rafael José Iorio, Jr and Valéria de Magalhães Iorio [found here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/fourier-analysis-and-partial-differential-equations/39312A08B4D4F25F65F39581D229285B).